# Attach debugger in netbeans with embedded jetty

Tags: debugging, netbeans, jetty, jpda

I'm looking for days now how to attach my debugger in netbeans. 
So we have a Start.java class where the jetty is embedded. Similar to this http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty
So I start my web application by running this Start.java file. Everything works fine till the point where I want to debug. I've seen multiple how to's for eclipse and the very few I found for netbeans didnt help.

Does anyone have a clue?
In the project properties, under actions, I added 
`Env.MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xverify:none -Xnoclassgc -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n`

under Run file via main()
and Debug file via main()

when I attach the java debugger (jpda) it seems as if its running but its ignoring the breakpoints

Has anyone any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project properties -> actions: Debug file via main() I had added as mentioned above

```
Env.MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xverify:none -Xnoclassgc
```

whitch attached the debugger but not with my project. I added `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}`

to my exc.args and now its working perfectly!

```
exec.args=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n -classpath %classpath ${packageClassName}
```

This is the complete config of my Debug file via main() and Run file via main()

```
exec.args=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n -classpath %classpath ${packageClassName}
exec.executable=java
exec.classpathScope=${classPathScope}
jpda.listen=true
Env.MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xverify:none -Xnoclassgc
```

Answer (score 5):

Do following step to debug JSP web  maven project in Netbeans using jetty

1. Right click on project and click on properties
2. Go to actions and select `"Debug Project"` actions
3. Click on ok button
4. Again right click  on project go to Custom->Goals
5. Set Goals `jetty:run`
6. Set properties `jpda.listen=maven`
7. Click on ok button